# How to get the confidence of my prediction on caffe-mobile?

Tags: android, android-ndk, convolution, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to get the confidence of my prediction on caffe-mobile. In python its easy to get it, I just did:

```
prediction = mNet.predict([image])
print prediction
```

And I get the following output:

```
[ 0.32693869  0.20242123  0.26447725  0.20616281]
```

I have four classes, so these are the confidence of my classes.

On android if I do this:

```
int[] prediction = caffeMobile.predictImage(imgPath);
for (int i = 0; i < prediction.length; i++) {
    Log.i("Caffe", String.valueOf(prediction[i]));
}
```

My output is just the predicted class.

```
Caffe 1
```

I think that I have to implement this method, because the size of `prediction` is 1. But how do I change and what files must I change to get it work on android?

So, how can I do this using [caffe-mobile](https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib) for android?

UPDATE:

I added the following to `caffe_jni.cpp`:

```
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL
Java_com_sh1r0_caffe_1android_1lib_CaffeMobile_getConfidence(JNIEnv *env,
                                                        jobject thiz,
                                                        jstring imgPath) {
  CaffeMobile *caffe_mobile = CaffeMobile::Get();
  vector<float> confidence = caffe_mobile->GetConfidence(jstring2string(env, imgPath));

  jfloatArray result;
  result = env->NewFloatArray(4);
  if (result == NULL) {
    return NULL; /* out of memory error thrown */
  }
  env->SetFloatArrayRegion(result, 0, 4, &confidence[0]);
  return result;
}
```

Then I added this to `caffe_mobile.cpp`:

```
vector<float> CaffeMobile::GetConfidence(const string &img_path) {
  const vector<float> probs = Forward(img_path);
  return probs;
}
```

I added this to caffe android class:

```
public native float[] getConfidence(String imgPath);
```

And called this method

```
float[] confidence = caffeMobile.getConfidence(imgPath);
```

But, it only return a rounded value ( I think ).

```
Log.i("Caffe","LENGTH: " + String.valueOf(confidence.length));
```

The output if `4`, ( I have 4 classes );

So:

```
for (int i = 0; i < confidence.length; i++) {
    Log.i("Caffe", String.valueOf(confidence[i]));
}
```

If try to classify an image labelled as 0, I get the following output:

```
Caffe 1.0
Caffe 0.0
Caffe 0.0
Caffe 0.0
```

or if try to classify an image labelled as 2, this is the output:

```
Caffe 0.0
Caffe 1.0
Caffe 0.0
Caffe 0.0
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible?